# Multiplication product of elements in each row of a 2-D matrix using python

Tags: python, listview, arraylist

```py
a = [[1 2 3],
     [4 2 1],
     [1 3 4]]
```

the answer should be [6 8 12]

I have tried a lot but I'm not able to solve it please help.

Comment: that isn't valid code.  Can you put the matrix in the datastructure you plan on using?

Answer (score 1):

```
import math

a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 2, 1], [1, 3, 4]]
print([math.prod(r) for r in a])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a= [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4]

print([a[idx]*a[idx-1]*a[idx-2] for idx, _ in enumerate(a) if (idx+1)%3==0 ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`numpy.prod`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html)

```
import numpy as np

a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 2, 1],[1, 3, 4]]
print(np.prod(a, 1))
```

---

```
[6  8 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

without using math or numpy:

```py
def product(myList) :
    result = 1
    for i in myList:
        result = result * i
    return result

a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 2, 1], [1, 3, 4]]
b = [product(l) for l in a]

print(b) # [6, 8, 12]
```